# how to use static assert to check custom datatype in template

Tags: c++

I have a class MyClass.

Now, I want to write a function which will return either a unique_ptr or a shared_ptr depending on how a function is called like this:

```
using MyClassUnique = std::unique_ptr<MyClass>;
using MyClassShared = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>;
template<typename T>
T createMyClass(int x)
{
   static_assert(std::is_same<T, MyClassUnique >::value ||
        std::is_same<T, MyClassShared >::value, "Not a matching type");
   return T(new MyClass(x));
}
```

And while using, I will use it like this:

```
int ptr = createMyClass<int>(5); //throws compilation error "Not a matching type"
MyClassUnique ptr = createMyClass<MyClassUnique>(5); //works file
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
std::unique_ptr ptr = std::unique_ptr(new MyClass(5));
```

This is not allowed due to some constraint.

Comment: Normally you just lean on the type checking mechanism directly, like both of these inherit from something, or you have two specialized functions, not a template. It's kind of counter-productive to have a template, and then go and restrict it to just two types.

Comment: Just use std::make_shared and std::make_unique, in this form, createMyClass doesn't seem to be like a useful abstraction.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273101/can-constexpr-if-else-bodies-return-different-types-in-constexpr-auto-function

Comment: `Is there a better way` "better"? There are _other_ ways to do it. How to measure what is "better"? "Better" in what way? The title is `how to use static assert to check custom datatype in template` yet you seem to know the answer - you already use `static_assert` in the code shown and it "works". So why do you ask how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 with you could use a concept:

```
template<class T>
concept MyClassUniqueOrShared = std::same_as<T, MyClassUnique> || std::same_as<T, MyClassShared>;

template<MyClassUniqueOrShared T>
T createMyClass(int x) {
    return T(new MyClass(x));
}
```

You could use SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, MyClassUnique> || std::is_same_v<T, MyClassShared>, T>::type
createMyClass(int x) {
   return T(new MyClass(x));
}
```

Comment: typo? `&&`  vs `||` in the concept?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes :p

Answer (score 1):

If you have C++17 you can use `if constexpr` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<class> inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;

struct MyClassUnique
{
    MyClassUnique(int n) {}
};

struct MyClassShared
{
    MyClassShared(int n) {}
};


template<typename T>
auto createMyClass(int n)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, MyClassUnique>)
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>(n);
    }
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, MyClassShared>)
    {
        return std::make_shared<T>(n);
    }
    else
    {
        static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "Invalid template parameter");
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto a = createMyClass<MyClassUnique>(1);
    auto b = createMyClass<MyClassShared>(1);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j8Kq56)

Note you can use `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` this way which are better than using using `new`.