move or copy -- major compilers disagree, who's right?
A class below is a wrapper that either keeps a reference on lvalue or a copy of rvalue. The latter is either copied or moved depending on specialization.
This is a very common problem when using rvalue proxies, which must be moved or copied, while lvalues can be held by reference. For example, I'm using this in lambda capture, where the rvalue needs to be copied (if more than a single copy created) or moved otherwise.
template<class T, bool FWD>
struct fwd_or_copy_wrapper
{
    fwd_or_copy_wrapper(T&& t): _t(FWD ? std::forward<T>(t) : std::add_const_t<T>(t)) {}
private:
    T _t;
};

Deduction guide, not required for gcc, but required for MSVC, and fails to compile in clang.
template<class T, bool FWD>
fwd_or_copy_wrapper(T&& t) -> fwd_or_copy_wrapper<T, FWD>;

Two alias specializations, first doing move and the second doing copy:
template<class T>
using fwd_wrapper = fwd_or_copy_wrapper<T, true>;

template<class T>
using copy_wrapper = fwd_or_copy_wrapper<T, false>;

Gcc output is what I would expect here: binding reference for lvalue, and then either calling copy-ctor or move-ctor for rvalue.
But MSVC output is unexpected. Not only it does superfluous calls to copy-ctor, it also performs copy instead of move for fwd_wrapper.
Demo is here
The question is: how to modify the wrapper class to make all three compilers to do the right thing?
Additionally, there are questions about MSVC and clang, whether they have bugs that need to be reported.
UPDATE:
The following change in constructor fixed the problem with MSVC:
template<class T, bool FWD>
struct fwd_or_copy_wrapper
{
    fwd_or_copy_wrapper(T&& t) requires FWD : _t(std::forward<T>(t)) {}
    fwd_or_copy_wrapper(T&& t) requires (!FWD) : _t(t) {}
    /* the rest is the same */
private:
    T _t;
};

This requires the latest MSVC compiler (VS 2022 17.11) as it triggered another bug in previous versions.

It should be noted that in fwd_or_copy_wrapper(T&& t) t is not a forwarding reference but just a plain rvalue reference, unless T is a lvalue reference type.  You would need to make the constructor a template to make it a forwarding reference.

@NathanOliver -- it's forwarding if you taking into account deduction guide, the type is deduced either as T& or T and std::forward applying && to it does exactly the right thing.

C++ is statically typed, so the result of FWD ? A : B is not "A if FWD is true, else B." It is "A if FWD is true, else B, both covered to the common type of A and B." I suspect that it is the conversion to a common type that is causing the problem. (Just like how the type of FWD ? std::string() : "x" is std::string even if FWD is false.)

Another solution is if constexpr (FWD) return A; else return B; because the deduced return type will ignore discarded statements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273101/can-constexpr-if-else-bodies-return-different-types-in-constexpr-auto-function

@MSalters -- it would if you could use if expression in member intialization, perhaps it would work if wrapped in lambda in initializer, like _t([&]->auto&&         {              if constexpr(FWD)                  return std::forward<T>(t);              else                  return std::add_const_t<T>(t);         }())

@Gene: You can also use a (named) member function..
